# Incremental Summation of Expressions in CVXPY

Tags: python, cvxpy

I need to incrementally build a [CVXPY](https://www.cvxpy.org/index.html) expression, e.g. a sum.
At the moment I'm using:

```py
sum_expr = None

for ...
   var = cp.Variable(...)
   if sum_expr:
      sum_expr += var
   else:
      sum_expr = var

# use sum_expr
```

Is there a cleaner, more concise way to do this?

Is there some default NOP/Null/Void/Nil value I can use to initialize `sum_expr` so that I can avoid the `if` statement and just use the `+=`?

Comment: Answer is here: https://github.com/cvxgrp/cvxpy/issues/970

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is to use the neutral element for the specific operation, e.g. `cp.Constant(0)` for summation and `cp.Constant(1)` for products.

There is no built-in "Null" expression, but adding a single neutral element to the parse tree does not really affect performance.

Longer thread with answer is [here](https://github.com/cvxgrp/cvxpy/issues/970).